# How to get the key of parent node in Realtime Firebase Database

Tags: android, json, firebase-realtime-database

RealTime Firebase Database structured in JSON format when data is pushed in it. So if JSONObject has another JSONObject in RealTime Database, then how to get the "key" name of that JSONObject.

Given below image is the structure of Firebase Realtime Database where I want to fetch the key "January" and key "2018-01-23" from structure, how can I do it.

I tried listeners of the Firebase by passing "Neeraj" because it is known to me, but I am getting fail to fetch what is the next key name of JSON structure.

[image]

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Neeraj` node is a direct child of your Firebase-root, to get that data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference dateRef = rootRef.child("Neeraj").child("January").child("2018-01-22");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String inStatus = dataSnapshot.child("inStatus").getValue(String.class);
        String inTime = dataSnapshot.child("inTime").getValue(String.class);
        String outSatus = dataSnapshot.child("outSatus").getValue(String.class);
        String outTime = dataSnapshot.child("outTime").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", "Neeraj" + " / " + dataSnapshot.getRef().getParent().getKey() + " / " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        Log.d("TAG", inStatus + " / " + inTime + " / " + outSatus + " / " + outTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
dateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
1 / 11:58:12 pm / 1 / 11:58:12 pm
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Is this what you want? `Neeraj / January / 2018-01-22`.

Comment: You using `dataSnapshot.getRef().getParent().getKey()` and `dataSnapshot.getKey()` for the last two. Have you tried my updated answer?

Comment: Ok. Keep me posted.

Comment: Thanks it worked..!!!. DataSnapshot will tak us to last child node of tree and from there I will be able to get the key value. But here I'm getting null values for inStatus, inTime ,outSatus and outTime. No worry I'll figure that out. Thanks for help.